# сохранение роли в БД

Tags: python, sqlite, discord, discord.py

Почему при запуске пишет:   File "voice.py", line 54, in on_ready
if cursor.execute(f'SELECT role_id FROM users WHERE role.id = {member.id}').fetchone() is None:
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: role_id

код:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready ():
    print ('готово')

    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
        role_id BIGINT,
        id BIGINT   
    )""")


    for guild in client.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            if cursor.execute(f'SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}').fetchone() is None:
                cursor.execute(f'INSERT INTO users VALUES ("{member}", {member.id}, 0 )')
                connection.commit()
            if cursor.execute(f'SELECT role_id FROM users WHERE role.id = {member.id}').fetchone() is None:
                cursor.execute(f'INSERT INTO users VALUES ("{member}", {member.id}, 0 )')
            else:
                pass

    connection.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что вы создаете таблицу, но не сохраняете ее и пытаетесь сделать запись в дальнейшем.

Добавьте `connection.commit()` после

```
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
        role_id BIGINT,
        id BIGINT   
    )""")
```

---

У вас в коде, в этой строке

```
if cursor.execute(f'SELECT role_id FROM users WHERE role.id = {member.id}').fetchone() is None:
```

вместо названия столбца `role_id` используется `role.id`.

---

Также, при записи вы пытаетесь записать 3 колонки:

```
("{member}", {member.id}, 0 )
```

но при это у вас в таблице их только две

Comment: не помогло( проблема та же

Comment: дополнил ответ, посмотрите